# How to edit button in salesforce content detail page

Tags: content

[image]How to get the edit button displaying inside a content detail page? I have given a delete content permission to the library administrator, through which I am trying to edit the content. I have set all permissions on the  profile - "Manage Salesforce CRM Content", everything seems to be correct. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Library Permission of the user from Viewer to Library Administrator. The Edit will be visible.

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes the user is library administrator ,but still he is not getting the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go a step further than what the previous answer suggested. You need to edit the Library Permissions. Go into Setup-->Customize-->Salesforce Files-->Content Permissions-->EDIT Library Administrator Permission as that is what's assigned to the user-->Make sure that Add Content Checkbox is checked. [image: Library Permissions]